# Fetched SQL statement (PDO) returns an object at the 0 index o the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I fetch some results from an sql statement I did using PDO and whenever I put it on an array it goes like this:

`initialize Object ( [conn:protected] => PDO Object ( ) [container:protected] => Array ( [0] => 1,Philippine Tax,2 ) )`

Whenever I FOREACH the returned array, it gives an error that it can't display an object. Here is my code:

```
<?php
class initialize{
    protected $conn = NULL;
    protected $container = array();

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = $this->connect();

        $ed_fetch = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
        if ($ed_fetch->execute()){
            while ($row = $ed_fetch->fetch( )){
                array_push($this->container, $row[0] . ',' . $row[1] . ',' . $row[2]);
            }
        }

        return $this->container;
    }

    protected function connect(){
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", 'root');
        if (!$this->conn){
            echo "Error, could not connect to the database, contact the administrator";
        }
        else{
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My display:

```
$new = new initialize();
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead. The reason you are getting what you are is because you are trying to get info on the object, essentially a mapping of the object. If you are trying to return an array, you need to return it through a method, not so much through the `__construct` as a return though.

```
class Initialize
    {
        protected   $conn       =   NULL;
        protected   $container  =   array();
        protected   $creds;
        protected   $username;
        protected   $password;

        public  function __construct($creds = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", $username = 'root', $password = '')
            {
                $this->creds    =   $creds;
                $this->username =   $username;
                $this->password =   $password;
                $this->conn     =   $this->connect();
            }

        public function Fetch($sql)
            {
                $ed_fetch   =   $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                $ed_fetch->execute();

                if ($ed_fetch->rowCount() > 0){
                        while ($row = $ed_fetch->fetch()){
                                $this->container[]  =   $row[0].','.$row[1].','.$row[2];
                            }
                    }

                return $this->container;
            }

        protected function connect()
            {
                try {
                        $this->conn = new PDO($this->creds,$this->username,$this->password);
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo "Error, could not connect to the database, contact the administrator<br/>";  //. $e->getMessage() . 
                        die();
                    }
            }
    }

    $query  =   new Initialize();
    $array  =   $query->Fetch("SELECT * FROM table");

    print_r($array);
```